# PS3 Media Server Installation on 14.10

Tags: server, 14.10, media, ps3

I've been trying to install PS3 media server on 14.10 using the following link:

http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13046

Upon entering the second: sudo apt-get update it starts downloading and I end up getting the following:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/happy-neko/ps3mediaserver/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And upon the 3rd command:

```
renier@renier-ProLiant-MicroServer:~$ sudo apt-get install ps3mediaserver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ps3mediaserver
```

I am a noob in ubuntu and have switched from server 2008 in order to use the GPT support for hybrid drives greater than 2TB.

Appreciate any help in this at all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that there is no package available for 14.10 - the PPA only has packages for versions up through 13.04. [See the PPA info here](https://launchpad.net/~happy-neko/+archive/ubuntu/ps3mediaserver) for supported versions. It appears that the PPA hasn't been updated for going on two years. You can try contacting the maintainer to see if there are any plans to update the packages, but it appears that this is an abandoned project given the lack of updates.

Comment: Thanks! Any other suggestions to use as a media server for a PS3?

Comment: PS3's seem pretty good about using any DLNA server. You might look at [Plex](http://plex.tv) which has specific support for the PS3, PS4 and XBox.